# How to compile and run Turbo compiler (windows 7) in command prompt

Tags: turbo-c++

If turbo coplier is installed in windows 7 using DOSBox then how can u compile and run through Command prompt. I have tried using environment variable -path setting.But when i run the program as

```
C:\TurboC++\Disk\TurboC3\BIN\tcc Test.c
Turbo c++ Version 3.00 Copyright (c) 1992 Borland 
International:
Error test.c 1:Unable to open include file 'stdio.h'
Error test.c 2:Unable to open include file 'conio.h'
*** 2 errors in Compie ***

      Available memory 4134742

C:\TurboC++\Disk\TurboC3\BIN\
```

==================================
test.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
printf("Hello command prompt");
getch();
}
```

Comment: Is there a good reason that you're using Turbo C++? This is a 21 year old compiler that supports only very immature subsets of C++ and C. Using this compiler will very likely teach you bad coding practices as is already visible from your archaic code sample.

There are many better modern compilers out there.

Answer (score 0):

You are not telling the compiler where to look for default include files.  Usually it is -I and the directory path.

Answer (score 0):

TurboC++, like  most other C/C++ compilers from that era, reads its include file locations from either the system environment (an environmental variable named `INCLUDE`, IIRC) or from a command line parameter you provide.

For info on setting environmental variables, you can do that in the AUTOEXEC.BAT file for your DOSBox configuration, or from a batch file that you set up to run the TurboC++ compiler:

```
SET INCLUDE=Whatever_Include_Path_You_Need
tcc %1
```

For specifying it from the command line, type `tcc /?` from a command prompt. It will display all of the possible command line switches and options.